# How do I recreate a Rasbberry pi OS from partition images?

Tags: raspberry-pi, dd, raspbian

I have a Raspberry PI that I cant take offline.

Using DD I have backed up the /dev/root/ and the /dev/mmcblk0p5 boot partitions on to a windows network share.

How do I restore images taken using DD from Windows?

Using windows I need to rebuild the OS on a new SD card. (That will allow me to put a second RPi online and remove the other for maintenance without creating any gap in service)

I have tried using the Win32DiskImager utility to restore the images. But it's only useful for restoring whole disk images, not for rebuilding the OS using the multiple partitions on a new SD card.

Is there a Windows app I can use to put both the image files on the SDcard? Is there a GParted that runs in windows?

Should I put a base Noobs image on the SD card and then replace the boot and root partitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I'd do the whole thing from the pi (assuming you have spare USB ports).

Instead of dding the partitions, dd the entire disk to a new SD card via a USB adapter.

Lets say the SD card via USB is mounted on `/dev/sdb` (you can check this by looking in `dmesg` when you insert it - make sure you get the whole disk device name, if it says there is a `/dev/sdb1`, it has found a partition, and you should use `/dev/sdb` which means the whole disk).

Then you can do

```
dd if=/dev/mmcblk0 of=/dev/sdb bs=1m
```

The SD card will be an exact replica of the one you already have.

Comment: I think you have saved me some legwork, I think it's working over the network.  If using /mmcblk0 instead of /mmcblk0p5 gets me a complete disk image then I'm golden.  Will know soon.